# Given a list of indexes, how to do multi-time add operate without a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The title maybe a little confused, I will explain here:
Given an array:

```
arr = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
```

And given a list of indexes:

```
idxes = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])
```

and a number list to add:

```
e = np.array([0.1, 0.35, 0.5, 0.2])
```

What I want is to get a result like that:

```
arr[idxes] += e
```

which means

```
[arr[0], arr[0], arr[1], arr[0]] + [0.1, 0.35, 0.5, 0.2]
```

so that `arr[0]` is added three times that `arr[0] = arr[0] + 0.1 + 0.35 + 0.2 = 1.65` and `arr[1]` is added one time that `arr[1] = arr[1] + 0.5 = 2.5`,
How can I do that directly without a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
np.add.at(arr, idxes, e)
arr
```

Output:

```
array([1.65, 2.5 ])
```